# Tracking users last form field on page unload

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms, adobe-analytics

I am trying to store the last page and the last form field that the user was focused on prior to his unexpected exit from the page (did not click continue), but my solution is not working. 
I am using the onbeforeunload event on the pages themselves, I fully realise that this event does not work consistently across all the browsers, but  I could not figure out a way to this in an another way.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                        if (fieldName != null && fieldName.length > 0) {
                            var formName = location.pathname.substring(1);
                            if (typeof (TrackFormField) == 'function') {
                                try {
                                    TrackFormField(formName, fieldName);
                                }
                                catch (err) {

                                }
                            }
                        }

                };
```

TrackFormField is  function in a separate file that just assigns the value to the property

```
function TrackFormField(formName, fieldName) {
        if (formName) {
            s.prop23 = formName + ":" + fieldName;
        }

        sendOmniture();
    }
```

And sendOmniture does the following:

```
function sendOmniture() {
        var s_code = s.t(); if (s_code) document.write(s_code)
    }
```

The weird thing is that at times it works, but usually I don't see the prop23 neither in the analytics debugger nor in  Fiddler.

After some debugging I found out that s_code for some reason is undefined in the send omniture function. 
What can I do to fix this issue ?

Comment: To be clear, the actual http request to Adobe will show this as query string parameter `c23=[your value]` if you do not see this (when you see that it actually is making a request) then you must have code elsewhere that is overwriting `s.prop23` (I would start with looking in `s_doPlugins` function since there is (presumably) nothing else between setting `s.prop23` and that `s.t()` call) or else `TrackFormField` is not what is getting triggered!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the  window.onbeforeunload event will kill the (s) object in most cases before it has a chance to execute.

What about using a Direct Call rule with Adobe DTM that will fire your function on focus change? That way you don't need to tie any action to the onbeforeunload event.

Hope this helps.